# Shiva Ve'esrim Ushlosh Meyot - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows three hundred twenty-seven?

### ?שבעה ועשרים ושלוש מאות - מי יודע

The traditional Passover song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea) implies a possible presupposition that there is a Jewish significance to be found for each [natural number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number). Accordingly, there is an [ongoing series](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) on Mi Yodeya that is attempting to unearth significant Judaism facts about each number, in sequence.

What significant Judaism facts are there about the number 327? The more significant within Judaism and the more intrinsically dependent on the value 327, the stronger the answer. Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

I hereby recommend not using lazy gematriyas for answers... and this line does NOT have any puns on it!

Comment: *Yeyasher kochacha sheshibarta et ha* taboo. Note that the last line in the previous question, which you've copied here, contains two puns on lazy gematria for 326, but not for 327

Comment: If there are puns, i don't see them... And why did you remove the top line? It's sort of like credit to you for the text. ;)

Comment: All I can say is, if you don't see the puns, keep looking! You can also try to see if they pop out when you try to generate lazy-gematria puns for 326 yourself. Unfortunately, I can't think of any good ones for 327. 328, on the other hand, will be easy. The top line was misspelled and irrelevant to the question at hand.

Comment: @IsaacMoses [Not necessarily misspelled](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/5151/scimonster)......

Comment: @Shokhet [yes, necessarily](/u/2)

Comment: @IsaacMoses Oh. Now I see.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Sorry about that. Just one more mistake from the iPad keyboard...

Comment: @IsaacMoses כוש?

Comment: @Scimonster That's #127. One more to go.

Comment: @IsaacMoses No idea. But i removed it, and used the text from 325.

Comment: That text contains one pun for a lazy gematria of 325, but none for 327.

Comment: no gematria here -- the 327 was a GREAT Chevy engine that carried many Jews wherever they wanted to go, and they made it there on time..even a bit early!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Even Sapir volume 2 - page 224](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22332&st=&pgnum=235&hilite=) says that the [Sefer Hoshea from Trei Asar](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14261&st=&pgnum=3) spans a period of 327 years from Uziyahu Hamelech until the year Alexander Mokdon arrived.

> ספר הושע ספר שנים עשר נביאים שלש מאות ועשרים ושבע שנים  מן עוזיהו המלך
>   עד השנה שבא אלכסנדר מוקדון

Answer (score 6):

The Sefer [Chazoinim](http://hebrewbooks.org/42160) which was printed in the late 16th century includes 327 Piyutim for Shabbos, Yom Tov, and Rosh Hashana.

Thanks to [Seridei Shira](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39579&st=&pgnum=2) for this information.